# inheriting properties in php

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, properties

I have a superclass which contains properties & methods for setting them

```
class Super{
    private $property;

    function __construct($set){
        $this->property = $set;
    }
}
```

then I have a subclass that needs to use that property

```
class Sub extends Super{
    private $sub_property

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->sub_property = $this->property;
    }
}
```

but I keep getting an error

```
Notice: Undefined property: Sub::$property in sub.php on line 7
```

where am I going wrong?

Comment: *(tip)* Since this is your second question about basic OOP features in PHP today, I suggest to have a look at the chapter [Classes and Objects in the PHP Manual](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is saying that it's trying to find a local variable called $property which doesn't exist.

To refer to $property in object context, as you intended, you need `$this` and the arrow.

```
$this->sub_property = $this->property;
```

secondly, the line above will fail as is because `$property` is `private` to the `Super` class. Make it `protected` instead, so it's inherited.

```
protected $property;
```

Third, (thanks Merijn, I missed this), Sub needs to extend Super.

```
class Sub extends Super
```

Comment: It is very confusing if you edit your question like that. In future, please just accept the answer or edit your question but **add** new code that shows your solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your $sub_property protected instead of private.

Answer (score 2):

You'll also need to specify that the subclass extends from the superclass:

```
class Sub extends Super {
   // code
}
```

Comment: my bad, it is already like that in the code, have edited question to reflect this