# How to pass View constants in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

So basically I am designing my PHP based website to a newer and more supported framework. Currently my website in written in Kohana 2.3.4 and I am moving to Yii2 framework. The biggest problem I am facing is the difference is that on my Kohana Site, I used constants for all my HTML for the case of translating but now I have no problem since I can just use: `Yii::t()`

Though I have solved this problem I needed to know how to pass my Settings Array to all actions on every controller. The settings are loaded from my `SettingsQuery` model and should be accessed from all the views in the app ie. Something like global constants. I have tried a few tips I got from my research but nothing is working as the scenario is a bit different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038912/how-to-pass-param-from-controller-to-layout-in-yii2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987416/how-do-i-pass-a-global-variable-in-main-layout-page-before-content-in-yii2).

I have tried a way to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761091/inheriting-properties-in-php) way but it works only when I have static values for my settings. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two possible places I know to declare global constants in Yii 2.0 are :

1. Your application [Entry
   Scripts](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-entry-scripts.html#defining-constants) for global variables to which hole processes may depends. Maybe for serious init settings like which **modules** to activate and what **components** to disable.
2. `[your app]/config/params.php` file which I thing is the proper
   place for placing your global settings because that's why it was
   built for. If you open that file, you'll already find this inside :

   ```
   return [
       'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com',
   ];
   ```

   This information is accessible any where in your application within
   this :

   ```
   $admin_email = \Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'] ;
   ```

   So in order to relate it to your **SettingsQuery model**, you will
   need to create a **Bootstrap** class which will need to create an
   instance from your model and use it to set the global constants when
   bootstrapping your app.
        @arogachev have a great example about how to create a **Bootstrap** class in [this StackOverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345064/how-to-configure-global-uploadpath-and-uploadurl-in-yii2#answer-29345318)

Comment: Let me try this out and tell you how it goes.

Comment: how do you think I could do this for module params? I want to define variables only to a certain module. I havent managed to do it since I am still reading on implementing the application bootstrap.

Comment: sorry i've seen your comment when using mobile but forget to answer it when reaching my laptop. Modules have an `init()` method which seems a good place to do so. [here is how it works - from docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html#module-classes).